# How do I get values instead of keys from object for use with vue.js binding (:class)

Tags: wordpress, vue.js, vimeo

I'm very new to Vue syntax, so please forgive me (and feel free to correct!) my terminology and assumptions. In short, I have a very simple goal, to get values from an object where currently I am getting key names.

In the code I am trying to modify, there is a Vue object called "tags," part of a complete "video" object (returned from Vimeo), that, when bound in a Vue "x-template" script to html - like so:

```
<figure class="vimeography-thumbnail" :class="video.tags" >
```

...produces output like this:

```
<figure data-v-de73d604 data-v-5a40afb8 class="vimeography-thumbnail name canonical name canonical name canonical" index="18">
```

The output we need instead would look more like this:

```
<figure data-v-de73d604 data-v-5a40afb8 class="vimeography-thumbnail hands feet eyes" index="18">
```

In other words, "hands," "feet," and "eyes" would be the values of "canonical" for the set of three "tags." The "data" and "index" elements being output are, I believe, irrelevant.

I got as far as I did through some investigatory hacking around, and, though the result is wrong, I can see from page source that "name" and "canonical" are the correct key names, that the values I need are also present, and that the number of pairs of keys for each video thumbnail is as would be expected given each specific Vimeo video's number of tags.

I do see a lot of discussion about iterating over the object (or is it really an array?), but the `:class` shorthand seems already to be doing that, so I wonder if there isn't a simple shorthand way to get the values instead of keys. I tried `video.tags.values` and `video.tags[canonical]`just for the heck of it, but no luck.

Just to provide a larger context, the script is a template customization script for a WordPress plugin - Vimeography - that has already done the job of constructing the needed variables from the Vimeo API.

The larger template - for modifying gallery thumbnails - looks like this:

```
<script type="text/x-template" id="vimeography-timber-thumbnail"> 
    <figure class="vimeography-thumbnail" :class="video.tags" >    
    <img class="vimeography-thumbnail-img" :src="thumbnailUrl" :alt="video.name" />    
        <figcaption>      
            <h2 class="vimeography-title">{{video.name}}</h2>  
            <div class="vimeography-description" v-html="video.description"></div><!-- try two -->
            <router-link class="vimeography-link" :to="this.query" :title="video.name" exact exact-active-class="vimeography-link-active">View more      </router-link>    
        </figcaption>  
    </figure>
</script>
```

A typical tags object looks like this in page source:

```
"tags":[{"name":"neck massage","canonical":"neckmassage"},{"name":"release","canonical":"release"},{"name":"shoulder pain","canonical":"shoulderpain"}]
```

So, as you can see if you return to the output example above, I'm getting the first and second key names "name" and "canonical" in sequence, separated by spaces, when what I need is each second key value.

On request - a video object - the "tags" appear around midway in it.

`"466907727":{"uri":"\/videos\/466907727","name":"Headache Relief w\/ Ruth","description":"Give yourself some time with this one. If you feel a headache coming on or you can't get rid of one, try out these techniques to release face, jaw, and ear muscles that tense up throughout the day.","link":"https:\/\/vimeo.com\/466907727","duration":"11:43","width":1280,"height":720,"embed":{"buttons":{"like":true,"watchlater":true,"share":true,"embed":false,"hd":false,"fullscreen":true,"scaling":true},"logos":{"vimeo":false,"custom":{"active":true,"url":"https:\/\/i.vimeocdn.com\/player\/415649.png?mw=100&mh=100","link":"https:\/\/bodyworksdw.com","sticky":true}},"title":{"name":"show","owner":"show","portrait":"hide"},"playbar":true,"volume":true,"speed":false,"color":"ffffff","uri":"\/presets\/120692845","html":"<iframe src=\"https:\/\/player.vimeo.com\/video\/466907727?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;speed=0&amp;badge=0&amp;autopause=0&amp;player_id=0&amp;app_id=27459\" width=\"1280\" height=\"720\" frameborder=\"0\" allow=\"autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture\" allowfullscreen title=\"Headache Relief w\/ Ruth\"><\/iframe>","badges":{"hdr":false,"live":{"streaming":false,"archived":false},"staff_pick":{"normal":false,"best_of_the_month":false,"best_of_the_year":false,"premiere":false},"vod":false,"weekend_challenge":false}},"created_time":"2020-10-10T17:17:42+00:00","privacy":{"view":"disable"},"pictures":{"uri":"\/videos\/466907727\/pictures\/972886256","active":true,"type":"custom","sizes":[{"width":100,"height":75,"link":"https:\/\/i.vimeocdn.com\/video\/972886256_100x75?r=pad","link_with_play_button":"https:\/\/i.vimeocdn.com\/filter\/overlay?src0=https%3A%2F%2Fi.vimeocdn.com%2Fvideo%2F972886256_100x75&src1=http%3A%2F%2Ff.vimeocdn.com%2Fp%2Fimages%2Fcrawler_play.png"},{"width":200,"height":150,"link":"https:\/\/i.vimeocdn.com\/video\/972886256_200x150?r=pad","link_with_play_button":"https:\/\/i.vimeocdn.com\/filter\/overlay?src0=https%3A%2F%2Fi.vimeocdn.com%2Fvideo%2F972886256_200x150&src1=http%3A%2F%2Ff.vimeocdn.com%2Fp%2Fimages%2Fcrawler_play.png"},{"width":295,"height":166,"link":"https:\/\/i.vimeocdn.com\/video\/972886256_295x166?r=pad","link_with_play_button":"https:\/\/i.vimeocdn.com\/filter\/overlay?src0=https%3A%2F%2Fi.vimeocdn.com%2Fvideo%2F972886256_295x166&src1=http%3A%2F%2Ff.vimeocdn.com%2Fp%2Fimages%2Fcrawler_play.png"},{"width":640,"height":360,"link":"https:\/\/i.vimeocdn.com\/video\/972886256_640x360?r=pad","link_with_play_button":"https:\/\/i.vimeocdn.com\/filter\/overlay?src0=https%3A%2F%2Fi.vimeocdn.com%2Fvideo%2F972886256_640x360&src1=http%3A%2F%2Ff.vimeocdn.com%2Fp%2Fimages%2Fcrawler_play.png"},{"width":1280,"height":720,"link":"https:\/\/i.vimeocdn.com\/video\/972886256_1280x720?r=pad","link_with_play_button":"https:\/\/i.vimeocdn.com\/filter\/overlay?src0=https%3A%2F%2Fi.vimeocdn.com%2Fvideo%2F972886256_1280x720&src1=http%3A%2F%2Ff.vimeocdn.com%2Fp%2Fimages%2Fcrawler_play.png"},{"width":1280,"height":720,"link":"https:\/\/i.vimeocdn.com\/video\/972886256_1280x720?r=pad","link_with_play_button":"https:\/\/i.vimeocdn.com\/filter\/overlay?src0=https%3A%2F%2Fi.vimeocdn.com%2Fvideo%2F972886256_1280x720&src1=http%3A%2F%2Ff.vimeocdn.com%2Fp%2Fimages%2Fcrawler_play.png"},{"width":1280,"height":720,"link":"https:\/\/i.vimeocdn.com\/video\/972886256_1280x720?r=pad","link_with_play_button":"https:\/\/i.vimeocdn.com\/filter\/overlay?src0=https%3A%2F%2Fi.vimeocdn.com%2Fvideo%2F972886256_1280x720&src1=http%3A%2F%2Ff.vimeocdn.com%2Fp%2Fimages%2Fcrawler_play.png"},{"width":1280,"height":720,"link":"https:\/\/i.vimeocdn.com\/video\/972886256_1280x720?r=pad","link_with_play_button":"https:\/\/i.vimeocdn.com\/filter\/overlay?src0=https%3A%2F%2Fi.vimeocdn.com%2Fvideo%2F972886256_1280x720&src1=http%3A%2F%2Ff.vimeocdn.com%2Fp%2Fimages%2Fcrawler_play.png"},{"width":1920,"height":1080,"link":"https:\/\/i.vimeocdn.com\/video\/972886256_1920x1080?r=pad","link_with_play_button":"https:\/\/i.vimeocdn.com\/filter\/overlay?src0=https%3A%2F%2Fi.vimeocdn.com%2Fvideo%2F972886256_1920x1080&src1=http%3A%2F%2Ff.vimeocdn.com%2Fp%2Fimages%2Fcrawler_play.png"}],"resource_key":"0e08692aa74f2e89587bd88aedf898a1faa1ccb9","default_picture":false},"tags":[{"name":"Jaw","canonical":"jaw"},{"name":"Head","canonical":"head"},{"name":"Recover","canonical":"recover"}],"stats":{"plays":3},"metadata":{"connections":{"texttracks":{"uri":"\/videos\/466907727\/texttracks","options":["GET","POST"],"total":0}}},"user":{"account":"business"},"download":[{"quality":"sd","type":"video\/mp4","width":426,"height":240,"expires":"2021-05-16T10:05:23+00:00","link":"https:\/\/player.vimeo.com\/play\/2073102730?s=466907727_1621159523_101bba513873dd67b93c563f09e28890&loc=external&context=Vimeo%5CController%5CApi%5CResources%5CUser%5CAlbum%5CVideosController.&download=1&filename=Headache%2BRelief%2Bw%252F%2BRuth139.mp4","created_time":"2020-10-10T17:19:59+00:00","fps":29.97,"size":32299937,"md5":"fcad390159d07049c597c47dd7edc921","public_name":"SD 240p","size_short":"30.8MB"},{"quality":"sd","type":"video\/mp4","width":960,"height":540,"expires":"2021-05-16T10:05:23+00:00","link":"https:\/\/player.vimeo.com\/play\/2073102727?s=466907727_1621159523_03598ebe80a895414613bd3cef32af54&loc=external&context=Vimeo%5CController%5CApi%5CResources%5CUser%5CAlbum%5CVideosController.&download=1&filename=Headache%2BRelief%2Bw%252F%2BRuth165.mp4","created_time":"2020-10-10T17:19:59+00:00","fps":29.97,"size":143540809,"md5":"553cd5d74d4ab59cc16547b486c82a30","public_name":"SD 540p","size_short":"136.89MB"},{"quality":"sd","type":"video\/mp4","width":640,"height":360,"expires":"2021-05-16T10:05:23+00:00","link":"https:\/\/player.vimeo.com\/play\/2073102718?s=466907727_1621159523_613694ef950f06a2a4a06376d9c03708&loc=external&context=Vimeo%5CController%5CApi%5CResources%5CUser%5CAlbum%5CVideosController.&download=1&filename=Headache%2BRelief%2Bw%252F%2BRuth164.mp4","created_time":"2020-10-10T17:19:59+00:00","fps":29.97,"size":56848778,"md5":"282afb947f67e072bfb44b84557ff231","public_name":"SD 360p","size_short":"54.22MB"},{"quality":"hd","type":"video\/mp4","width":1280,"height":720,"expires":"2021-05-16T10:05:23+00:00","link":"https:\/\/player.vimeo.com\/play\/2073102708?s=466907727_1621159523_0d0c2d785bc32949b4eca945a220741a&loc=external&context=Vimeo%5CController%5CApi%5CResources%5CUser%5CAlbum%5CVideosController.&download=1&filename=Headache%2BRelief%2Bw%252F%2BRuth174.mp4","created_time":"2020-10-10T17:19:59+00:00","fps":29.97,"size":244431967,"md5":"8db87793d97332351b77aba3d1e5a042","public_name":"HD 720p","size_short":"233.11MB"}],"status":"available","video_id":"466907727","id":466907727,"human_created_time":"October 10, 2020","thumbnail_tiny":"https:\/\/i.vimeocdn.com\/video\/972886256_295x166?r=pad","thumbnail_tiny_with_play_button":"https:\/\/i.vimeocdn.com\/filter\/overlay?src0=https%3A%2F%2Fi.vimeocdn.com%2Fvideo%2F972886256_295x166&src1=http%3A%2F%2Ff.vimeocdn.com%2Fp%2Fimages%2Fcrawler_play.png","thumbnail_small":"https:\/\/i.vimeocdn.com\/video\/972886256_640x360?r=pad","thumbnail_small_with_play_button":"https:\/\/i.vimeocdn.com\/filter\/overlay?src0=https%3A%2F%2Fi.vimeocdn.com%2Fvideo%2F972886256_640x360&src1=http%3A%2F%2Ff.vimeocdn.com%2Fp%2Fimages%2Fcrawler_play.png","thumbnail_medium":"https:\/\/i.vimeocdn.com\/video\/972886256_1280x720?r=pad","thumbnail_medium_with_play_button":"https:\/\/i.vimeocdn.com\/filter\/overlay?src0=https%3A%2F%2Fi.vimeocdn.com%2Fvideo%2F972886256_1280x720&src1=http%3A%2F%2Ff.vimeocdn.com%2Fp%2Fimages%2Fcrawler_play.png","thumbnail_large":"https:\/\/i.vimeocdn.com\/video\/972886256_1280x720?r=pad","thumbnail_large_with_play_button":"https:\/\/i.vimeocdn.com\/filter\/overlay?src0=https%3A%2F%2Fi.vimeocdn.com%2Fvideo%2F972886256_1280x720&src1=http%3A%2F%2Ff.vimeocdn.com%2Fp%2Fimages%2Fcrawler_play.png"},`

Comment: Can you provide the shape of the `video.tags` object for clarity?

Comment: I'm adding what I've got to the question, and I also made a correction (I need "canonical," not "name") - although I'm not sure what you mean by "shape."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple inlined method within your script template tag should suffice:

```
:class="
  video.tags.reduce((classes, obj) => {
    classes.push(obj.canonical)

    return classes
  }, []) 
"
```

This should be sufficient enough to reduce down the existing array of objects into a simple array of string values.

As for why this happens - in the object syntax for classes, vue looks at the left hand assignment and will apply it if the right hand assignment is truthy. in your case, the indices are applied because the values of them are strings, which are truthy.

Comment: Thanks... When I apply that code (to the figure tag, inline), the script fails with "carry is not defined" errors.

Comment: @CKMacLeod So sorry, I was writing from my phone and made careless errors. Fixed.

Comment: No need to apologize! Your solution works, and I even mostly understand it, although Vue syntax remains somewhat obscure to me. It's still impressively compact, all things considered. I guess the built-in assumption is of a different most common practice for getting css classes. I can now move, I believe, to the next stage of implementation: using them, so thank you very much.

Comment: (Pretty sure it's going to work, and nicely - thanks again!)

Answer (score 0):

couldn't get your problem exactly, if you want to print the value call it by its property name ".name" as you did, but you have to be sure that video is a single object.

```
<figure
      v-for="(item, index) in tags"
      :v-key="index"
      data-v-de73d604
      data-v-5a40afb8
      :class="item.name + item.canonical"
      class="vimeography-thumbnail"
      :index="18 + index"
    ></figure>
```

with tags array

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <!-- ..-->
    <figure
      v-for="(item, index) in tags"
      :v-key="index"
      data-v-de73d604
      data-v-5a40afb8
      :class="item.name + ' ' + item.canonical"
      class="vimeography-thumbnail"
      :index="18 + index"
    ></figure>
    <!-- ..-->
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from "./components/HelloWorld";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      tags: [
        { name: "neck massage", canonical: "neckmassage" },
        { name: "release", canonical: "release" },
        { name: "shoulder pain", canonical: "shoulderpain" },
      ],
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

[image]

//new Update

```
<template>
  <div id="app">

{{ video.tags }}
 <figure
      v-for="(item, index) in video.tags"
      :v-key="index"
      data-v-de73d604
      data-v-5a40afb8
      :class="item.name + ' ' + item.canonical"
      class="vimeography-thumbnail"
      :index="18 + index"
    ></figure>

  </div>
</template>


<script>
export default {
  mounted(){
var get = {
      466907727: {
        uri: "/videos/466907727",
        name: "Headache Relief w/ Ruth",
        description:
          "Give yourself some time with this one. If you feel a headache coming on or you can't get rid of one, try out these techniques to release face, jaw, and ear muscles that tense up throughout the day.",
        link: "https://vimeo.com/466907727",
        duration: "11:43",
        width: 1280,
        height: 720,
        embed: {
          buttons: {
            like: true,
            watchlater: true,
            share: true,
            embed: false,
            hd: false,
            fullscreen: true,
            scaling: true,
          },
          logos: {
            vimeo: false,
            custom: {
              active: true,
              url: "https://i.vimeocdn.com/player/415649.png?mw=100&mh=100",
              link: "https://bodyworksdw.com",
              sticky: true,
            },
          },
          title: { name: "show", owner: "show", portrait: "hide" },
          playbar: true,
          volume: true,
          speed: false,
          color: "ffffff",
          uri: "/presets/120692845",
          html:
            '<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/466907727?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;speed=0&amp;badge=0&amp;autopause=0&amp;player_id=0&amp;app_id=27459" width="1280" height="720" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen title="Headache Relief w/ Ruth"></iframe>',
          badges: {
            hdr: false,
            live: { streaming: false, archived: false },
            staff_pick: {
              normal: false,
              best_of_the_month: false,
              best_of_the_year: false,
              premiere: false,
            },
            vod: false,
            weekend_challenge: false,
          },
        },
        created_time: "2020-10-10T17:17:42+00:00",
        privacy: { view: "disable" },
        pictures: {
          uri: "/videos/466907727/pictures/972886256",
          active: true,
          type: "custom",
          sizes: [
            {
              width: 100,
              height: 75,
              link: "https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/972886256_100x75?r=pad",
              link_with_play_button:
                "https://i.vimeocdn.com/filter/overlay?src0=https%3A%2F%2Fi.vimeocdn.com%2Fvideo%2F972886256_100x75&src1=http%3A%2F%2Ff.vimeocdn.com%2Fp%2Fimages%2Fcrawler_play.png",
            },
            {
              width: 200,
              height: 150,
              link: "https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/972886256_200x150?r=pad",
              link_with_play_button:
                "https://i.vimeocdn.com/filter/overlay?src0=https%3A%2F%2Fi.vimeocdn.com%2Fvideo%2F972886256_200x150&src1=http%3A%2F%2Ff.vimeocdn.com%2Fp%2Fimages%2Fcrawler_play.png",
            },
            {
              width: 295,
              height: 166,
              link: "https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/972886256_295x166?r=pad",
              link_with_play_button:
                "https://i.vimeocdn.com/filter/overlay?src0=https%3A%2F%2Fi.vimeocdn.com%2Fvideo%2F972886256_295x166&src1=http%3A%2F%2Ff.vimeocdn.com%2Fp%2Fimages%2Fcrawler_play.png",
            },
            {
              width: 640,
              height: 360,
              link: "https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/972886256_640x360?r=pad",
              link_with_play_button:
                "https://i.vimeocdn.com/filter/overlay?src0=https%3A%2F%2Fi.vimeocdn.com%2Fvideo%2F972886256_640x360&src1=http%3A%2F%2Ff.vimeocdn.com%2Fp%2Fimages%2Fcrawler_play.png",
            },
            {
              width: 1280,
              height: 720,
              link: "https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/972886256_1280x720?r=pad",
              link_with_play_button:
                "https://i.vimeocdn.com/filter/overlay?src0=https%3A%2F%2Fi.vimeocdn.com%2Fvideo%2F972886256_1280x720&src1=http%3A%2F%2Ff.vimeocdn.com%2Fp%2Fimages%2Fcrawler_play.png",
            },
            {
              width: 1280,
              height: 720,
              link: "https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/972886256_1280x720?r=pad",
              link_with_play_button:
                "https://i.vimeocdn.com/filter/overlay?src0=https%3A%2F%2Fi.vimeocdn.com%2Fvideo%2F972886256_1280x720&src1=http%3A%2F%2Ff.vimeocdn.com%2Fp%2Fimages%2Fcrawler_play.png",
            },
            {
              width: 1280,
              height: 720,
              link: "https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/972886256_1280x720?r=pad",
              link_with_play_button:
                "https://i.vimeocdn.com/filter/overlay?src0=https%3A%2F%2Fi.vimeocdn.com%2Fvideo%2F972886256_1280x720&src1=http%3A%2F%2Ff.vimeocdn.com%2Fp%2Fimages%2Fcrawler_play.png",
            },
            {
              width: 1280,
              height: 720,
              link: "https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/972886256_1280x720?r=pad",
              link_with_play_button:
                "https://i.vimeocdn.com/filter/overlay?src0=https%3A%2F%2Fi.vimeocdn.com%2Fvideo%2F972886256_1280x720&src1=http%3A%2F%2Ff.vimeocdn.com%2Fp%2Fimages%2Fcrawler_play.png",
            },
            {
              width: 1920,
              height: 1080,
              link: "https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/972886256_1920x1080?r=pad",
              link_with_play_button:
                "https://i.vimeocdn.com/filter/overlay?src0=https%3A%2F%2Fi.vimeocdn.com%2Fvideo%2F972886256_1920x1080&src1=http%3A%2F%2Ff.vimeocdn.com%2Fp%2Fimages%2Fcrawler_play.png",
            },
          ],
          resource_key: "0e08692aa74f2e89587bd88aedf898a1faa1ccb9",
          default_picture: false,
        },
        tags: [
          { name: "Jaw", canonical: "jaw" },
          { name: "Head", canonical: "head" },
          { name: "Recover", canonical: "recover" },
        ],
        stats: { plays: 3 },
        metadata: {
          connections: {
            texttracks: {
              uri: "/videos/466907727/texttracks",
              options: ["GET", "POST"],
              total: 0,
            },
          },
        },
        user: { account: "business" },
        download: [
          {
            quality: "sd",
            type: "video/mp4",
            width: 426,
            height: 240,
            expires: "2021-05-16T10:05:23+00:00",
            link:
              "https://player.vimeo.com/play/2073102730?s=466907727_1621159523_101bba513873dd67b93c563f09e28890&loc=external&context=Vimeo%5CController%5CApi%5CResources%5CUser%5CAlbum%5CVideosController.&download=1&filename=Headache%2BRelief%2Bw%252F%2BRuth139.mp4",
            created_time: "2020-10-10T17:19:59+00:00",
            fps: 29.97,
            size: 32299937,
            md5: "fcad390159d07049c597c47dd7edc921",
            public_name: "SD 240p",
            size_short: "30.8MB",
          },
          {
            quality: "sd",
            type: "video/mp4",
            width: 960,
            height: 540,
            expires: "2021-05-16T10:05:23+00:00",
            link:
              "https://player.vimeo.com/play/2073102727?s=466907727_1621159523_03598ebe80a895414613bd3cef32af54&loc=external&context=Vimeo%5CController%5CApi%5CResources%5CUser%5CAlbum%5CVideosController.&download=1&filename=Headache%2BRelief%2Bw%252F%2BRuth165.mp4",
            created_time: "2020-10-10T17:19:59+00:00",
            fps: 29.97,
            size: 143540809,
            md5: "553cd5d74d4ab59cc16547b486c82a30",
            public_name: "SD 540p",
            size_short: "136.89MB",
          },
          {
            quality: "sd",
            type: "video/mp4",
            width: 640,
            height: 360,
            expires: "2021-05-16T10:05:23+00:00",
            link:
              "https://player.vimeo.com/play/2073102718?s=466907727_1621159523_613694ef950f06a2a4a06376d9c03708&loc=external&context=Vimeo%5CController%5CApi%5CResources%5CUser%5CAlbum%5CVideosController.&download=1&filename=Headache%2BRelief%2Bw%252F%2BRuth164.mp4",
            created_time: "2020-10-10T17:19:59+00:00",
            fps: 29.97,
            size: 56848778,
            md5: "282afb947f67e072bfb44b84557ff231",
            public_name: "SD 360p",
            size_short: "54.22MB",
          },
          {
            quality: "hd",
            type: "video/mp4",
            width: 1280,
            height: 720,
            expires: "2021-05-16T10:05:23+00:00",
            link:
              "https://player.vimeo.com/play/2073102708?s=466907727_1621159523_0d0c2d785bc32949b4eca945a220741a&loc=external&context=Vimeo%5CController%5CApi%5CResources%5CUser%5CAlbum%5CVideosController.&download=1&filename=Headache%2BRelief%2Bw%252F%2BRuth174.mp4",
            created_time: "2020-10-10T17:19:59+00:00",
            fps: 29.97,
            size: 244431967,
            md5: "8db87793d97332351b77aba3d1e5a042",
            public_name: "HD 720p",
            size_short: "233.11MB",
          },
        ],
        status: "available",
        video_id: "466907727",
        id: 466907727,
        human_created_time: "October 10, 2020",
        thumbnail_tiny: "https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/972886256_295x166?r=pad",
        thumbnail_tiny_with_play_button:
          "https://i.vimeocdn.com/filter/overlay?src0=https%3A%2F%2Fi.vimeocdn.com%2Fvideo%2F972886256_295x166&src1=http%3A%2F%2Ff.vimeocdn.com%2Fp%2Fimages%2Fcrawler_play.png",
        thumbnail_small: "https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/972886256_640x360?r=pad",
        thumbnail_small_with_play_button:
          "https://i.vimeocdn.com/filter/overlay?src0=https%3A%2F%2Fi.vimeocdn.com%2Fvideo%2F972886256_640x360&src1=http%3A%2F%2Ff.vimeocdn.com%2Fp%2Fimages%2Fcrawler_play.png",
        thumbnail_medium:
          "https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/972886256_1280x720?r=pad",
        thumbnail_medium_with_play_button:
          "https://i.vimeocdn.com/filter/overlay?src0=https%3A%2F%2Fi.vimeocdn.com%2Fvideo%2F972886256_1280x720&src1=http%3A%2F%2Ff.vimeocdn.com%2Fp%2Fimages%2Fcrawler_play.png",
        thumbnail_large:
          "https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/972886256_1280x720?r=pad",
        thumbnail_large_with_play_button:
          "https://i.vimeocdn.com/filter/overlay?src0=https%3A%2F%2Fi.vimeocdn.com%2Fvideo%2F972886256_1280x720&src1=http%3A%2F%2Ff.vimeocdn.com%2Fp%2Fimages%2Fcrawler_play.png",
      },
    };
// here we check if the getting data  is array or object and make it okay to video object.

    get == Array.isArray()
        ? (this.video = get[0])
        : (this.video = get[Object.keys(get)]);

  },
  data(){
    return{
          video:{

    }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: where tags is array of objects : "tags":[{"name":"neck massage","canonical":"neckmassage"},{"name":"release","canonical":"release"},{"name":"shoulder pain","canonical":"shoulderpain"}]

Comment: Thanks - no luck so far, but I'll be looking at variations. Note both the data and index statements are already generated/extracted dynamically from "video," which is declared elsewhere (multiple videos identified by Vimeo ID, gathered in a video_set object in turn under the highest level template object). I don't really understand how Vue binding works, but I don't see where  "tags" would be extracted from the video object in your code.  So, I've tried leaving out the index and also using video.tags instead of tags, without luck. Also, it doesn't do any harm, but I don't need item.name

Comment: add space between :class="item.name + ' ' + item.canonical"

Comment: tags that y give it in the code, you are getting it from get request and i just put it in vue data function that return an object,

 data(){
 return{
   tags:[{"name":"neck massage","canonical":"neckmassage"},{"name":"release","canonical":"release"},{"name":"shoulder pain","canonical":"shoulderpain"}] 

  }
}

Comment: can you console.log video or just print {{ video }} in html and see what is inside , if its object or array.

Comment: I've added the code for an entire video - which is defined by that name elsewhere, as one among others in the "video_set" that make up the content of the gallery.

Comment: Check the last code, put in mind this, be sure what kind of data y are receiving from your api, if u ask for single item y will receive an object, or multiple items which it ll be in array even if y ll get only one item, u still receive array with only one item or maybe 0 item if there is no items yet.

Comment: I really do appreciate your efforts, but I don't understand what you're trying to convey with the additional code as far as solving the main issue is concerned.

Comment: i thought you were sucking at ".name" since you past the long object into code.
that's nice to hear the issue is solved, have great day.